# How to unit test the python code using mock patch?

Tags: python, mocking, patch

I want to unit test the following code snippet

```
def extract_features_from_bytes(self, binary: bytes) -> str:
    with TimingMetric("fx_time") as fx_timing_metric:
        fv = self.feature_extractor.extract_features_from_bytes(binary)
    if self.metrics_reporter:
        self.metrics_reporter.report_metric(fx_timing_metric)
    return fv
```

Basically, I am trying to collect feature extraction time using TimingMetric and report it using `self.metrics_reporter`. `metrics_reporter` is of type `MetricsReporter` class. Now, I need to mock the following function within the test:

```
self.feature_extractor.extract_features_from_bytes(binary)
```

This is because the time taken for feature extraction is uncertain . The idea is to mock the call using a sleep function (e.g. `time.sleep(10)`), and then check if the time reported to metrics reporter matches the sleep duration. We need to mock feature extractor class actual method and also mock of MetricsReporter is needed. Using patch those mock instances can be passed to the test.

Any idea how we can write unit test for the above code snippet?

I tried to do the following, but it seems the mock function is incorrect:

```
##################
# Classifier
##################
@pytest.mark.classification
class TestClassifierBase:

    @pytest.fixture
    def mocked_stats_client_and_class(mocker):
        mock_stats_client = MagicMock()
        mock_stats_client_class = mocker.patch("dsci_core.metrics.lib.StatsClient")
        mock_stats_client_class.return_value = mock_stats_client
        return mock_stats_client, mock_stats_client_class

    @pytest.fixture
    def mocked_stats_client_and_reporter(mocked_stats_client_and_class):
        mocked_stats_client, _ = mocked_stats_client_and_class
        reporter = MetricsReporter()
        return mocked_stats_client, reporter

    def test_extract_features_from_bytes(self, test_classifier, mocked_stats_client_and_reporter):
        mock_stats_client, reporter = mocked_stats_client_and_reporter
        metric_name = "my_metric" 
        
        with TimingMetric(metric_name) as timing_metric:
            time.sleep(3)
        assert timing_metric.get_metric_value() == 3000
        reporter.report_metric(timing_metric)
        mock_stats_client.timing.assert_called_with(metric_name, 3000)
```

Comment: It's not obvious that you *need* to mock anything. What class does the method you want to test belong to, and how do you initialize an instance of the class in order to call the method? The attempt you show doesn't appear to even *call* the method you say you want to test.

Comment: The class name is `ClassifierBase`. It is a base class which is inherited by other classes. The method in question is being used by other internal functions under the base class.

Comment: The name of some class whose definition we can't see doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mock the `feature_extractor` and `metrics_reporter` objects of the test instance (`test_classifier`), not create a real `MetricsReporter` or `TimingMetric` - Don't get confused.

You will also need to ensure that your test is actually calling `extract_features_from_bytes` method of the `test_classifier` to ensure it works.

**Heres an example**:

```
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock
import time

@pytest.mark.classification
class TestClassifierBase:
    @pytest.fixture
    def feature_extractor_mock(self, mocker):
        mock = mocker.Mock()
        mock.extract_features_from_bytes = mocker.Mock(side_effect=lambda _: time.sleep(3))
        return mock

    @pytest.fixture
    def metrics_reporter_mock(self, mocker):
        return mocker.Mock()

    def test_extract_features_from_bytes(self, test_classifier, feature_extractor_mock, metrics_reporter_mock):
        test_classifier.feature_extractor = feature_extractor_mock
        test_classifier.metrics_reporter = metrics_reporter_mock

        test_classifier.extract_features_from_bytes(b'binary')

        metrics_reporter_mock.report_metric.assert_called_once()
```

**Example using patch calls**:

```
class TestClassifierBase:

    def test_extract_features_from_bytes(self, test_classifier):

        mock_feature_method = MagicMock(side_effect=lambda _: time.sleep(3))

        with patch.object(test_classifier, 'feature_extractor', create=True) as mock_extractor, \
             patch.object(test_classifier, 'metrics_reporter', create=True) as mock_reporter:

            mock_extractor.extract_features_from_bytes = mock_feature_method

            test_classifier.extract_features_from_bytes(b'binary')
                mock_extractor.extract_features_from_bytes.assert_called_once_with(b'binary')
            mock_reporter.report_metric.assert_called_once()
```

Comment: Where did `mocker` within two mock functions come from? Do we need to initialise it above ?

Comment: @Partho Sorry i didnt add the fact that mocker comes from https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/

Comment: Can the mock function be re-written using patch by making patch calls to feature extractor and metrics reporter?

Comment: @Partho sure - check now